# Swift4.2: Why func gameDidEnd(_:) no need to use game parameter but still declare in the function?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

According to the docs on swift.org, below is the original source code:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

```
class DiceGameTracker: DiceGameDelegate {
    var numberOfTurns = 0
    func gameDidStart(_ game: DiceGame) {
        numberOfTurns = 0
        if game is SnakesAndLadders {
            print("Started a new game of Snakes and Ladders")
        }
        print("The game is using a \(game.dice.sides)-sided dice")
    }
    func game(_ game: DiceGame, didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll diceRoll: Int) {
        numberOfTurns += 1
        print("Rolled a \(diceRoll)")
    }
    func gameDidEnd(_ game: DiceGame) {
        print("The game lasted for \(numberOfTurns) turns")
    }
}
```

I understand that func gameDidStart use a type DiceGame game parameter to access the .dice.sides, and also to check the reference object.

But `func gameDidEnd(_ game: DiceGame)` and `func game(_ game: DiceGame, didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll diceRoll: Int)`
these two function do not use the game parameter, why they still have to declare it? Is it a coding style of Apple? I really don't understand this part....

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes, this is a deliberate choice on Apple's part. The parameter is a required part of the protocol method declaration:

```
protocol DiceGameDelegate: AnyObject {
    func gameDidStart(_ game: DiceGame)
    func game(_ game: DiceGame, didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll diceRoll: Int)
    func gameDidEnd(_ game: DiceGame)
}
```

And so in order to conform to the protocol, it must include the parameter regardless of whether you make use of it or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask more detail about it? As you said it is a required part. Therefore, if I only declare the game: DiceGame in the gameDidStart func, the others two function don't. The complier will throw to me an error about I didn't conform correctly on this DiceGameDelegate protocol?

Comment: That's correct. In this example, and in Swift protocols, all methods must be declared exactly as defined.

Comment: I just try to remove the game: DiceGame from func gameDidEnd on my playground (I try to run the whole dice game demo code), and the complier didn't show any error which just give me pass the compiling  and print out correct information. So it is no need to add _ game: DiceGame parameter on every methods... It confused me again!

Comment: @WangduLin In the specific example given, you don't *need* the game parameter but other game delegates might want it. It's a common pattern for protocols that define [delegate](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift) APIs to put the delegating object as the first parameter for all functions in the protocol so one delegate can be used for multiple objects.